# Ocaml representation of values - Atoms

Tags: ocaml, bytecode, interpreter

I looked at the internal representation of some OCaml values. The representation of an empty array is an `atom(0)`, i.e. a block with `tag=0` and `size=0`. Empty arrays of floats are represented by an `atom(0)` too.

Is there any OCaml value represented by an atom with `tag > 0`? If not: for what purpose the OCaml bytecode set contains the `ATOM n` instruction?

Comment: Just for statistics: I inspected all bytecode files generated by a `make world` in ocaml-4.04.0 source tree, and I found no `ATOM n` instructions, nor `PUSHATOM n`. Only a lot of `ATOM0`...

Comment: The bytecomp and byterun code seems to think this is possible though I don't think it can happen naturally. Maybe other languages that generate magic OCaml (like Coq) use this. I don't know much about bytecode so I'll have to check with a colleague.

Comment: Update: apparently it's never used. The code exists because the possibility was interesting and it probably did not require much work to handle. Maybe it was useful, maybe it could be useful some day, maybe some obscure library relies on that instruction. It mainly exists because "we have no reason to remove it". Since I am not certain it's not used I'm not gonna put an answer but I guess that's the best you'll get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tag > 0 is used for constructors with arguments, which would make them not atoms. Constructors without arguments on the other hand are stored as int instead of blocks so again not atoms. So I think atom(0) is not used. Except ...

What about having a constructor with inline record that is empty?

```
# type t = A of int | B of { };;
Error: Syntax error
```

Seems empty records are not allowed. I can't think of another way to create a 0 size block with tag other than creating such a block directly. But that wouldn't be using the ATOM instruction.

Comment: Googling around, I found [a port of the OCaml bytecode interpreter  for PIC microcontrollers](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocapic/web/index.php?id=ocapic). In a [related paper](http://studia.complexica.net/Art/AC-JFLA11-07.pdf), the authors assert there is no OCaml value represented by an atom with tag <> 0.

Comment: Doesn't mean that some C code doesn't create some or someone uses the Obj module to make one. It's a valid thing for the Gc and abstract types could verry well use it for something.