# OCaml - int array and garbage collection

Tags: arrays, garbage-collection, ocaml

I know that a `float array` is represented at runtime as a block with `double_array_tag` and unboxed floats, so the garbage collector will not scan it (because `double_array_tag >= no_scan_tag`).

But what about an `int array`? How can the OCaml garbage collector know not to scan its fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, the garbage collector *will* scan the fields of an `int array`. For each field in turn, it will notice that it is unboxed and not pursue it any further.

This behaviour may not be very efficient; the main aspect though is that it is safe. It would not be safe in case of a `float array`, unless each individual `float` was boxed (and that in turn would be space-inefficient).

If the above (time-)inefficiency is a problem, the module `Bigarray` may provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks. That's just as I thought. And what about having another special representation, i.e. an int_array_tag?

Comment: @pifu that would mean faster GC but slower array access. Also, multiplying array representations is something the OCaml devs do not want to do (again). This is quite a controversial subject amongst people that delve into the source code between those that don't want anything to change, those that want the float array trick to be pulled out of the array type and those who have proposals similar to yours.

Comment: @PatJ thanks. It seems you knows OCaml internals pretty well. Maybe you could answer to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486650/ocaml-representation-of-values-atoms)?